# ReactJS Setting focus to an input in a tree structure

Tags: reactjs, treeview

I have an unlimited deep tree structure using ReactJS. My tree is comprised of nodes with the following model:

```
const tree = {
  id:"x",
  name: "node 1",
  children : [
      {
        id:"y",
        name:"sub node 1",
        children : []
      }
  ....
}
```

I am trying to set the focus to an input inside one of the child elements using refs (see https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). I determine which node to focus on using its id.

My Node component is:

```
class Node extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.setFocus = this.setFocus.bind(this)
}

setFocus(id) {
    if (this.props.node.id === id){
        this.inputWidget.focus()
        return true
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < this.subNodes.length; i++) {
        const t = this.subNodes[i]
        const result = t.setFocus(id)
        if (result) {
           return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

render() {
    const { node } = this.props
    const children = node.children

    // we store the component sub nodes so that we can iterate over them
    this.subNodes = []

    return (<div>
            <input type="text" ref={(input)=>{this.inputWidget = input}}
            {children.ma((n, index) =>
                <Node key={n.id} node={n}
                    ref={(main) => { this.subNodes.push(main) }} />
        </div>)
    }
}

export default Node
```

Then from a parent component I can trigger the setFocus(id) method (also using refs) on the whole tree.

Is this right approach or is there an easier / more efficient way? This way yields results that are not consistent. Especially once I mutate the tree structure (i.e. add a new node).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register both `ids` and `focusCallback` to your parent component in componentDidMount method.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Node extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.setFocus = this.setFocus.bind(this);
    }

    static propTypes = {
       registerNode: PropTypes.func,
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.registerNode(this.props.node.id, () => {
            this.inputWidget.focus();
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { node, registerNode } = this.props
        const children = node.children

        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" ref={(input)=>{this.inputWidget = input}}
                {children.map((n) =>
                    <Node registerNode={registerNode} key={n.id} node={n} />
            </div>
        )    
    }
}

export default Node
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Your parent component should provide `registerNode` method to your children nodes:

```js
class Head extends Component {
    nodes = {};
    
    registerNode = (id, focusCallback) => {
       this.nodes[id] = callback;
    };
    
    render() {
       const { tree } = this.props;
       
       return tree.map(node => 
           <Node registerNode={this.registerNode} key={node.id} node={node} />);
    }
    
}
```

Now you can set up focus to any input using `this.nodes[id]();`

Now we haven't to tree traversal because we just use map with ids. So we increase runtime speed
Also we remove extra `refs` on `Node` component.

Comment: Cool concept. Works nice! Thanks!

Comment: @checklist I'm glad to help, you can accept my answer then.